# how to automatically break line in tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am making a html based tag filter based on tailwind.

```
<div class="p-3 border-b">
    <div class="flex flex-col space-y-2 mt-2">
        <div class="flex flex-row space-x-2 text-sm" v-for="(filter,index) in filters" :key="index"> 
            <div class="w-16 text-base text-gray-700"> {{ filter.label }} </div>
            <div class=" flex flex-row space-x-5 text-gray-500 leading-6"> 
                <span class="cursor-pointer"> {{ categoryItem.name }} </span>
            </div>
        </div>                            
    </div>                            
</div> 


filters:[
    {
        name:'type',
        label:'Type',
        category:[
            {'name':'All'},
            {'name':'Animals, Plants & Land'},
            {'name':'Maintenance, Service & Repair'},
            {'name':'Management & Planning'},
            {'name':'Medical Technology'},
            {'name':'Transport'},
            {'name':'Storage, Dispatching & Delivery'},
            {'name':'Retail Sales & Customer Service'},
            {'name':'Medical Technologyy'},
            ....
        ]
    }                       
],
```

However since the number of category list is more than 30 items, the actual html page looks very wired since the tag list grows horizontally instead of breaking space into multiple lines.

[image]

how to deal with this?

Comment: could you please provide code in code sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the Tailwind CSS line clamp package to solve this problem.
[Here is a link](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/multi-line-truncation-with-tailwindcss-line-clamp) on how to use it.